# How to calculate "score" based on tags match

Tags: mysql

This will be a bit hard to explain. I have 3 tables, 1 for User, 1 for Interest & 1 for User_Interests. I want to calculate a score and add it to a new column. The score calculation is not that hard: Base points: 50. For each interest both users have I want to add 3 points to score, if a user has a interest that I don't have, I want to add 1 point to score. Is this possible using mySQL SELECT?

User:
| ID | 
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Interest:
| ID | title |

User_Interests:
| User_ID | Interest_ID |

This will however depends on my own ID. The end result I am looking is a list of all users and there score based on the tags from the user I supply. Let's say my user ID is 0:

Result:
| ID | score | 
| 1 | 69 |
| 2 | 54 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LEFT JOIN lists common interests and interests of the other user that this user does not have.

```
SELECT
    count(my.interest_id) AS common_interests,
    count(*) AS all_interests

FROM users_interests ui
LEFT JOIN users_interest my ON 
    (   my.user_id=$user_id 
    AND my.interest_id=ui.interest_id )
GROUP BY ui.user_id
```

The answer (according to the number of points you assign) would be common_interests*2 + all_interests

Comment: Thanks a lot, thanks to you I got a lot further. I was wondering right now I am using the current select query: 'code' SELECT u.* FROM User u LEFT JOIN User_Status us ON u.id = User_ID1 AND us.User_ID2 =?  WHERE gender =? and (us.Status != "FRIENDS" or us.status is null) 'code' Is there a way to combine the two query's together?

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmm..... I have no idea what you mean ;) Please edit your question to add this, and explain with a bit more detail what you want. What does this new query do?

Comment: LOL, have a nice day ;)